# order two mysql columns at the same time

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two date columns, `domain_renew_date` and `hosting_renew_date`.
I am trying to show the rows which need to be renewed in the next x days.
But if i order by one column then the other, some dates which are close to the current date will be ignored because the other column doesn't need renewing.

Is it possible to compare two columns for the largest value and use that value to order by?

This is what i have at the moment, but i have just found out 'greatest' doesn't do what im trying to make it do.

```
"SELECT *
FROM `domains` as Domain
WHERE (`domain_renew_date` < '".$date."' AND `domain_renew_date` != '0000-00-00')
OR (`hosting_renew_date` < '".$date."' AND `hosting_renew_date` != '0000-00-00')
ORDER BY greatest(`domain_renew_date`, `hosting_renew_date`) ASC"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or even more simple

`SELECT if(domain_renew_date > hosting_renew_date, domain_renew_date, hosting_renew_date) as greater_date

FROM domains

WHERE hosting_renew_date >=  '".date."' OR domain_renew_date >= '".$date."'
ORDER BY greater_date ASC`

Comment: This seems like exactly what i need, but doesn't seem to go in any order at all.. This is what i used:

SELECT *, if(domain_renew_date > hosting_renew_date, domain_renew_date, hosting_renew_date) as greater_date
FROM domains as Domain
ORDER BY greater_date ASC

Comment: I have run the query and it gives me a result where the records are ordered by the bigger of the 2 date - domain_renew_date or hosting_renew_date. If you want to order the result by the smaller one (the recent one) just turn the sing > to become SELECT *, if(domain_renew_date < hosting_renew_date, domain_renew_date, hosting_renew_date) as more_recent_date FROM domains as Domain ORDER BY more_recent_date ASC

Comment: If the ordering os not working, check your fields type. I am using DATE, but any DATE type should be workign also. It is working 100% on my machine.

Comment: I also get Unknown column 'greater_date' in 'where clause'
Even though the ORDER BY works fine??

Comment: You can not get "Unknown column" and have the order by working at the same time. Check your query again.

Comment: That's what confused me.. 
ORDER BY `greater_date` ASC
works fine but as soon as i add
WHERE `greater_date` > '0000-00-00'
i get
Unknown column 'greater_date' in 'where clause'

Comment: I saw what you mean, try running this SELECT *, if(domain_renew_date > hosting_renew_date, domain_renew_date, hosting_renew_date) as greater_date FROM domains as Domain WHERE hosting_renew_date > '$date' OR domain_renew_date > '$date' ORDER BY greater_date ASC

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm glad you received the same error as me. This seems great except i have to order it DESC as NULL goes to the top in ASC, but i can switch the result around after i query it.

Comment: I'm guessing if I set the two date columns to NOT NULL then they date would appear as 0000-00-00 and the sorting would work. Ill try and remember to up vote you when I have permission :)

Comment: You could at least accept the answer ;) There should be a "check" icon on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT if(domain_renew_date <= '".$date."', 'domain_renew_date', 'hosting_renew_date') as greterdate
FROM `domains` as Domain
WHERE (`domain_renew_date` < '".$date."' AND `domain_renew_date` != '0000-00-00')
OR (`hosting_renew_date` < '".$date."' AND `hosting_renew_date` != '0000-00-00')
ORDER BY greterdate ASC"
```

may this work for your requirement.

Thanks.